# How To Implement React Server Side Rendering With HMR in Webpack2?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, webpack, react-router

I am trying to implement server side rendering with my react app that uses HMR and need some clarification on my issues. There seems to be miscommunication between the server and the frontend but I'm not entirely sure why that is.

When I start my server, the browser loads the client side index.html and I am able to edit my site with HMR working just fine. However, when I navigate to another page besides the homepage, and I refresh the browser, the server then renders the html markup in my handleRender function. The sites html markup appears, however there is no css and HMR doesn't work.

To summarize, on first load, it renders the app client side, but upon refresh, it renders the app server side.  I'm thinking it might have to do with the way I am using `router.use(express.static(clientDir));` but I'm not sure. Any clarification would be helpful!

**Client side Index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>Base Template</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/bundle.css">
    </head>
    <body id="body">
        <div class="root"></div>
        <script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**React App index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './App'

const root = document.querySelector('.root');

// Wraps our App in AppContainer
const render = (Component) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AppContainer>
        <Component/>
      </AppContainer>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    root
  );
};

// Renders our application
render(App);

// Checks if there have been changes and accepts them.
// This activates HMR and refreshes modules in the browser
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}
```

**Express Server**

```
import express from 'express'
import React from 'react'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router'
import { resolve } from 'path'
import routes from './routes'

// Imports our React App
import App from '../client/scripts/App'

// Create Express App
const app = express();

// Set the port for our server
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)

// Use routes to check if the environment is prod || dev
app.use(routes)

// Use handleRender for SSR
app.use(handleRender)

function handleRender(req, res) {
  const context = {};

  const html = renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context} >
      <App/>
    </StaticRouter>
  )

  if (context.url) {
    res.writeHead(301, {
      Location: context.url
    })
    res.end()
  } else {
    res.write(`
      <!doctype html>
      <head>
        <title>Redux Universal Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/bundle.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="app">${html}</div>
        <script type="javascript" src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    `)
    res.end()
  }
}

export default app
```

**Routes for server**

```
import express, { Router } from 'express'
import { resolve } from 'path'
import { isDev } from '../utils'

const router = Router();
const clientDir = resolve(`${__dirname}/../../client`);

if (isDev()) {
  const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')
  const webpack = require('webpack')
  const webpackConfig = require('../../../webpack.config')
  const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware')

  const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig)

  // This compiles our app using webpack
  router.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
    noInfo: true
  }))

  // This connects our app to HMR using the middleware
  router.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler))
}

router.use(express.static(clientDir));

export default router
```